# Multiple select box values to CSV

Tags: php, arrays, forms, csv

I have the following multi select box in a HTML form:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="fruits">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option> 
    <option value="Peach" selected="selected">Peach</option> 
    <option value="Banana">Banana</option> 
    <option value="Grapes" selected="selected">Grapes</option> 
</select>
```

How can I convert the selected values into a string of comma separated values for inserting into the database?

I am using PHP.

Comment: Um, you *are* using PHP right?

Comment: Do you actually want a csv (a file type with it's own peculiarities for escaping) which may not work directly in a query but could be used to upload by some other mechanism?  Or do you want a way to combine an array of items for use in a direct query? Either way, be wary of answers that do not mention security as without it, this can be easily hacked for a sql injection attack.

Comment: @evan, by cvs I mean comma separated values, as posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PHP, I had to use `name="fruits[]"` (note the brackets) to get multiple values to post.

From there, you get an array for `$_POST['fruits']` (numerically indexed, values corresponding to what was selected), so `implode(',', $_POST['fruits'])` would give you the values as a comma separated string.

However, if you are worried about true CSV format, you will need to escape the delimiters and enclose the values (there could be commas in the values, for instance). If you are confident that none of the values will break the output, and `explode(',', $string)` will get you back your array, `implode()` is fine.

Also perhaps of interest:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Related:

- [Convert array into csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933668/convert-array-into-csv)
- [Any function to take an array of strings and return a CSV line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037111/any-function-to-take-an-array-of-strings-and-return-a-csv-line)

Comment: Oh and by the way, always sanitize your input and escape it properly for sql queries, as usual, even if using a `<select>` input where you have hard-coded the values and generally trust their integrity.